Why is Icom CS-51PLUS2 give me this error on one computer but not on another?
I'm using the Icom CS-51PLUS2 software to configure my Icom ID-51 PLUS2. I have it installed it two computers that have access to the same configuration files (shared with google drive).
One one computer, the software works fine, accepts all frequencies. On the other, when I open a file, it gives this warning signs for some frequencies, and when I save the file it just removes them:

I'm aware these frequencies are outside the ham radio band plan, but the radio can listen on them. Still, why two computers, both running same windows version and same Icom software, would have two different results?

Stab in  the dark: make sure both programs are exactly at the same version, and that the language and locality of both machines is set to the same. I've seen programs stumble over files because they used the localized version of some string reading function, which sadly interpreted the comma in a comma-separated file as decimal separator on a German machine, but of course worked on the American machines that were used by the commercial developers of that software.

I found a solution, but it's not a full explanation. In one of the computers I have cloned info from my radio. That's where I didn't have any errors. After cloning the info from the radio (from the micro sd card) on the other one, it started working correctly. So there's some band plan adjustment that happens to the software when reading the data but there are no settings I could find to explicitly make this band plan adjustment.

@clvrmnky I will create an answer if nobody else does. I thought someone else might have more details (and appreciate the karma). I don't think it's using the locale and I don't think a setting files has more permissive ranges. Once the software sees a setting files with more permissive ranges come from the radio, it changes its configuration for all setting files it opens. Very counter intuitive.
